# SQL - select all rows and replace column value(s) with max column value with identifier

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, max

I've looked at a various answers on stackoverflow for selecting the max value or replacing column values but I'm not can't seem to figure out how I could do both and return all the rows. Basically I want to return all rows but replace the value of a column in a given row if another row has a higher number in the same column and the same identifier.

I'm not an SQL expert and this has me scratching my head and pulling my hair out...  I'm hoping this can be done via a query without updating the data. Maybe I need to rework the data but this would be a huge manual task. Maybe I could do this in the view? I'd appreciate and be open to any suggestions for how to do this.

Below is an example of the view that is being queried. The **"code"** is the common field.

```
+-------+-------+-----------------------------------+   
| type1 | type2 | code | amt |                      |   
+-------+-------+-----------------------------------+  
| 1     | A     | 100  | 59                         |  
| 1     | B     | 200  | 75                         |  
| 2     | C     | 100  | 65   <-- Max for code 100  |  
| 2     | D     | 200  | 80   <-- Max for code 200  |  
| 3     | E     | 100  | 55                         |  
| 3     | F     | 200  | 70                         |  
+-------+-------+-----------------------------------+
```

I need to return all rows but replace the "amt" with the max value if the "code" is the same and the number is higher in another row. Here's an example of the output I'm looking for:

```
+-------+-------+------------------------------------------------+   
| type1 | type2 | code | amt |                                   |   
+-------+-------+------------------------------------------------+  
| 1     | A     | 100  | 65 <-- replaced w/max for code 100      |  
| 1     | B     | 200  | 80 <-- replaced w/max for code 200      | 
| 2     | C     | 100  | 65                                      |  
| 2     | D     | 200  | 80                                      |  
| 3     | E     | 100  | 65 <-- replaced w/max for code 100      |
| 3     | F     | 200  | 80 <-- replaced w/max for code 200      |
+-------+-------+------------------------------------------------+
```

The reason for trying this in a query is to keep the original data. Is this possible with a query or do I need to try to update the data instead? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this.

```
Select type1,type2,code,Max(Amt) Over(PARTITION BY Code) AS MaxAmt
from Table1
```

[**Sql Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b2d64/1)

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply! Your solution works as do the others but I now realize I need to expand upon or take this a bit further. Sorry, I'm a bit of a newbie with stackoverflow so not sure what I should do. Should I post an update to the question, ask a new expanded question or should I mark this answer as correct? Technically your answer is correct for how I asked the question. I'll edit my question as well and quote your solution.

Comment: its on you you can edit here or you can ask new  expanded question but while editing this question make sure the sole of this question didnt change otherwise all answer will become incorrect

Comment: That makes perfect sense. The core of the question is the same just need another step or two. Working on update now. Thanks again for the reply and help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select Type1,type2,code,Max(Amt) Over(PARTITION BY CODE) AS Val
from Table1
Order by Type1
```

**[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b2d64/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select type1,type2,code,Max(Amt) Over(PARTITION BY Code) AS amt
from Table1;
```

or

```
select t2.type1,t2.type2,t2.code,t1.max_amt amt from
table1 t2 inner join
(select max(amt) max_amt,code from table1 group by code)t1
on t1.code = t2.code;
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/009e0/7)